# Issue Creating Vector LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to create a vector and return it as a value using llvm. Here is what my code looks like:

```
  Value *ArrayAST::codeGen() {
    Type *dType = Type::getDoubleTy(mContext);
    Type *vectorType = VectorType::get(dType, 4);
    Value *emptyVector = UndefValue::get(vectorType);
    Constant *index0 = Constant::getIntegerValue(dType, llvm::APInt(32, 0));
    Value *numberValue = numbers[0] -> codeGen(); // double 1.000000e+00
    Value *fullVector = InsertElementInst::Create(emptyVector, numberValue, index0);
    return fullVector;
  }
```

This generates the following IR code:

```
define <4 x double> @x() {
entry:
  ret <4 x double> <badref>
}
```

But, as you can see above, there is an issue: `<badref>`. And when I try to run it, it fails to build:

```
llvm-as: out.ll:3:21: error: expected type
  ret <4 x double> <badref>
```

I am new to LLVM and I am not quite sure what the best way to fix this is.

#### Edit

If it is helpful, all of the code is on [GitHub here](https://github.com/pudility/superflow/tree/array).

#### Edit 2

If I am not mistaken (I totally could be) the IR code should look like this:

```
define <4 x double> @x() {
entry:
  %tmp4 = insertelement <4 x double> undef, double 1.000000e+01, i32 0
  ret <4 x double> %tmp4
}
```

Comment: I don't use the C++ API, but ... is the `insertelement` instruction not being added to the BB somehow?

Comment: @o11c that would make sense. I thought that the value returned by insert element would be the populated vector, but now that I look at it - that does not appear to be the case. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: That is probably correct. Like I said, I am very new to LLVM. What is the difference between `insertelement ` and `insertvalue`? ~~and is `insertelement ` different from what I have `InsertElementInst`?~~ Never mind I figured out they are the same. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @o11c that makes a lot of sense - thank you. I will see if I can implement `insertvalue`.

Comment: I tried using `insertvalue`: `InsertValueInst::Create(emptyVector, numberValue,  ArrayRef<unsigned>(0));` but, I got the same issue (`<badref>`).

Comment: Ugh, nevermind, I was wrong ... `insertvalue` is for structs/arrays. (I'm deleting obsolete comments now.) I guess you *have* to insert into a BB if the entire vector isn't made of constants. Probably you should be using the Builder.

Comment: Thanks - I will see if I can get that working.

Comment: @o11c inserting it into the builder worked perfectly - thank you so much - if you put that as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I don't feel confident writing an answer I haven't tested, and I don't use the C++ interface. You're allowed to answer the question yourself and mark it as accepted - you even get a badge for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not add the vector to my builder. The following did the trick for me:

```
Builder.Insert(fullVector);
```